# Fetch zone file for a domain name

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-hosting, whois, dns-zone

I'm trying to move 2 web-servers (with German and Russian domain names) from one hoster to another one (where I can create/maintain own DNS zones).

Before changing anything, I'd like to fetch and save the current zone file (sp?) for future reference.

On my CentOS 6 machine (not the web server to be moved) I've installed jwois packet and then I'm trying:

```
   whois mysite-1.ru
```

and

```
   whois mysite-2.de
```

but it returns some free-formatted (and differently-formatted) text. How do I fetch the zone file or whatever it is called (sorry, I have knowledge gaps there)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not use whois to perform zone transfers.

If zone transfers are permitted on name server for the current domain, then you could use a command like `host -t axfr mysite-1.ru ns1.mysite-1.ru` where ns1 is an authoritative name servers that permit zone transfers.

Comment: FYI - `host` is considered obsolete by its authors.

Comment: @Alnitak, which fork?  AFAIK, there are at least two separate forks of host.

Comment: @Zorecache the official ISC version.  Serious DNS heads use 'dig' :)

Answer (score 2):

You likely can't do zone transfers from the current DNS hosts - most don't permit it.

However given that you *ought* to know what names actually exist in your own zones, why not just ask for them?

```
 % dig mysite-1.ru. a       ; for 'bare' web site address
 % dig mysite-1.ru. mx      ; for email servers
 % dig www.mysite-1.ru. a   ; for www web site address
```

Repeat for any other names you happen to have, but the above would cover 99% of configurations.

There'll be `SOA` and `NS` records too, but you don't need to copy those - they'd be automatically set up by the new DNS host.